# How can I download streamed content in Safari?

Tags: safari

Activity Viewer seems to have been removed from Safari 5.2. I used it to download streamed content.

Is there a workaround to do that without Activity Viewer?

Comment: Safari 5.2? For Lion?

Comment: @lhf Safari 5.2 on Lion is [available as a developer preview](http://www.macrumors.com/2012/02/16/apple-seeds-safari-5-2-for-os-x-lion-to-developers/).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Develop menu item enabled?

If so, go to "Show Page Resources." Its very similar to the Activity Monitor and will show you the URL of contents. It's not exactly like it, but as close as you are going to get.

If you don't have the Develop menu enabled, go to:

Preferences-> Advanced -> Show Develop menu in menu bar